# Select last timestamp per each date

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array

A dataframe contains only a few timestamps per day and I need to select the latest one for each date (not the values, the time stamp itself). the df looks like this:

```
                               A      B      C
2016-12-05 12:00:00+00:00  126.0   15.0  38.54
2016-12-05 16:00:00+00:00  131.0   20.0  42.33
2016-12-14 05:00:00+00:00  129.0   18.0  43.24
2016-12-15 03:00:00+00:00  117.0   22.0  33.70
2016-12-15 04:00:00+00:00  140.0   23.0  34.81
2016-12-16 03:00:00+00:00  120.0   21.0  32.24
2016-12-16 04:00:00+00:00  142.0   22.0  35.20
```

I managed to achieve what i needed by defining the following function:

```
def find_last_h(df,column):
    newindex = []
    df2 = df.resample('d').last().dropna()
    for x in df2[column].values:
        newindex.append(df[df[column]==x].index.values[0])
    return pd.DatetimeIndex(newindex)
```

with which I specify which column's values to use as a filter to get the desired timestamps. The issue here is in the case of non unique values this might not work as desired.

Another way that is used is:

```
  grouped = df.groupby([df.index.day,df.index.hour])
  grouped.groupby(level=0).last()
```

and then reconstruct the timestamps but it is even more verbose. What is the smart way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) for truncate `times`:

```
idx = df.index.floor('D')
df = df[~idx.duplicated(keep='last') | ~idx.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df)
                         A     B      C
2016-12-05 16:00:00  131.0  20.0  42.33
2016-12-14 05:00:00  129.0  18.0  43.24
2016-12-15 04:00:00  140.0  23.0  34.81
2016-12-16 04:00:00  142.0  22.0  35.20
```

Another solution with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().groupby([df.index.date]).last().set_index('index')
print (df)
                         A     B      C
index                                  
2016-12-05 16:00:00  131.0  20.0  42.33
2016-12-14 05:00:00  129.0  18.0  43.24
2016-12-15 04:00:00  140.0  23.0  34.81
2016-12-16 04:00:00  142.0  22.0  35.20
```

---

`resample` and `groupby` `dates` only lost times:

```
print (df.resample('1D').last().dropna())
                A     B      C
2016-12-05  131.0  20.0  42.33
2016-12-14  129.0  18.0  43.24
2016-12-15  140.0  23.0  34.81
2016-12-16  142.0  22.0  35.20

print (df.groupby([df.index.date]).last())
                A     B      C
2016-12-05  131.0  20.0  42.33
2016-12-14  129.0  18.0  43.24
2016-12-15  140.0  23.0  34.81
2016-12-16  142.0  22.0  35.20
```

Comment: Works fine thank you! a question, is the | ~idx.duplicated(keep=False) really needed? i get the right boolean array already without it!

Comment: This code get all unique rows. Maybe in your real data are not, but if use your sample, 3. row without it will be removed.

Comment: This helped me do the opposite of what OP wanted (what I needed), which was remove the last entry of each day. Only need `df = df[idx.duplicated(keep='last')]`.

Comment: Does this depend on the order of the original dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

how about
`df.resample('24H',kind='period').last().dropna()` ?

Comment: what do you mean by lost times?

Comment: output are only dates with no times.

Comment: Check my answer and compare datetimeindex.

Comment: we can get that with kind='period' , edited the answer

Comment: This way I get as index the right dates but we loose the original times (it is all 12:00)

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby the date and just take the `max` of each datetime to get the last datetime on each date.

This may look like:

`df.groupby(df["datetime"].dt.date)["datetime"].max()`

or something like

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))["datetime"].max()`